# Método assertThat e uso do Matcher

Tags: java, testes, testes-de-unidade, junit

Para realizar testes unitários utilizando o método [`assertThat`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Assert.html#assertThat(T,%20org.hamcrest.Matcher)) no JUnit, é preciso passar um objeto [`Matcher`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/hamcrest/Matcher.html) como parâmetro.

```
public void assertThat(Object o, Matcher matcher){
        ...
}
```

Um exemplo de uso passando uma expressão:

```
@Test
public void testWithMatchers() {
    assertThat("1991", is("2019"));
}
```

Em relação a isso, eu gostaria de saber o seguinte:

- Por que é necessário utilizar o `Matcher`?
- Quais as vantagens de utilizá-lo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>*Fiz os testes abaixo com Java 8, [JUnit 4.12](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/) e [hamcrest-all 1.3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all/1.3)*</sup>

---

A princípio parece que usar [`assertThat`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Assert.html#assertThat(T,%20org.hamcrest.Matcher)) não seria necessário, já que é possível obter resultados similares com os demais métodos `assertXXX`. Exemplos:

```
// são equivalentes
assertThat("1991", is(algumValor)); // sendo que algumValor é uma String
assertEquals("1991", algumValor);

// são equivalentes
assertThat("1991", is(not("2019")));
assertNotEquals("1991", "2019");
```

Mas há algumas vantagens em usar `assertThat`. Suponha que eu tenho uma lista de `String` e um dos testes verifica se ela contém dois elementos específicos:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("abc", "def", "ghi");
assertTrue(list.contains("abc") && list.contains("xyz"));
```

Apesar de não ser um código tão complicado de entender, a versão com `assertThat` e o uso do *matcher* [`org.hamcrest.core.IsCollectionContaining`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all/1.3/org/hamcrest/core/IsCollectionContaining.html) (que possui o método [`hasItems`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all/1.3/org/hamcrest/core/IsCollectionContaining.html#hasItems(T...))) deixa o código mais legível e expressivo (pelo menos para quem sabe inglês):

```
// é quase uma frase em inglês (verifique se a lista tem os itens "abc" e "xyz")
assertThat(list, hasItems("abc", "xyz"));
```

Outra vantagem é a mensagem de erro, caso o teste falhe. Enquanto `assertTrue` só me deu um [`AssertionError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html) (sem nenhuma mensagem adicional, somente a linha que falhou), o `assertThat` deu esta mensagem:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: (a collection containing "abc" and a collection containing "xyz")
     but: a collection containing "xyz" was "abc", was "def", was "ghi"
```

Bem mais detalhada, descrevendo exatamente o problema (era esperado uma *collection* contendo "abc" e "xyz", mas ela só tinha "abc", "def" e "ghi").

Outro exemplo:

```
import static org.hamcrest.core.AllOf.allOf;
import static org.hamcrest.number.OrderingComparison.greaterThan;
import static org.hamcrest.number.OrderingComparison.lessThan;

int x = 5;
assertThat(x, allOf(greaterThan(1), lessThan(3)));
```

[`allOf`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all/1.3/org/hamcrest/core/AllOf.html#allOf(org.hamcrest.Matcher...)) recebe uma lista de *matchers* e verifica se todos são válidos. No caso, eu usei [`greaterThan`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all/1.3/org/hamcrest/number/OrderingComparison.html#greaterThan(T)) e [`lessThan`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all/1.3/org/hamcrest/number/OrderingComparison.html#lessThan(T)), ou seja, eu verifico se o número é maior que 1 **e** menor que 3. Como eu testei o valor `5`, o resultado é um `AssertionError` com a mensagem:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: (a value greater than <1> and a value less than <3>)
     but: a value less than <3> <5> was greater than <3>
```

Eu poderia fazer também:

```
int x = 5;
assertTrue(x > 1 && x < 3);
```

Mas novamente, o `AssertionError` não me dá uma mensagem descritiva, apenas a linha que deu o erro. E a versão com `assertThat` e os *matchers* torna o código mais próximo da linguagem natural (ou mais "expressivo", "legível", etc). Claro que isso depende da opinião de cada um, mas acho positivo você poder escolher a opção que achar melhor.

---

Além de poderem ser encadeados e combinados, como mostrado nos exemplos acima, ainda há a possibilidade de [criar seu próprio *matcher*](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/tutorial#writing-custom-matchers), caso seja necessário fazer alguma validação mais complexa e/ou específica, por exemplo.

A [documentação](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/tutorial#writing-custom-matchers) sugere que se crie uma subclasse de [`org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all/1.3/org/hamcrest/TypeSafeMatcher.html), que verifica se o valor sendo testado não é nulo e faz o *cast* para o respectivo tipo. Exemplo:

```
import org.hamcrest.Description;
import org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher;

public class MyMatcher extends TypeSafeMatcher<String> {
    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(String item) {
        // aqui pode ter o critério que você quiser
        // retorna true ou false, indicando se a String é válida ou não
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        // coloque uma mensagem bem descritiva aqui
        description.appendText("não passou nos critérios");
    }

    public static MyMatcher criterioXyz() {
        return new MyMatcher();
    }
}
```

E para usá-lo:

```
import static br.tests.MyMatcher.criterioXyz;

assertThat("string", criterioXyz());
```

<sup>Obviamente `criterioXyz()` deve ser substituído por um nome mais significativo que indique o que o *matcher* está verificando.</sup>

---

Claro que é possível fazer a mesma verificação usando os outros métodos `assertXXX`. Fica a seu cargo decidir se a complexidade extra dos *matchers* é um preço justo a se pagar para aumentar a legibilidade do código, além de ter mensagens de erro mais descritivas e a possibilidade de criar seus próprios *matchers* (este último item confesso que nunca precisei usar, mas pode ser que você precise e ache que vale a pena usar).